# Decide at runtime which class to call

Tags: c#, .net-core

In my method I have to decide how to handle the incoming data. The objects contain a string which defines how they should be handled.

Currently I have the following classes:

```
interface INotifier{
    string Name { get; }
    Task SendNotification(Notification);
}

public class WhatsappNotifier : INotifier{
    public string Name => "whatsapp";
    public async Task SendNotification(Notification notification){
        //Handle notification
    }
}

public class EmailNotifier : INotifier{
    public string Name => "email";
    public async Task SendNotification(Notification notification){
        //Handle notification
    }
}


public class NotificationCoordinator{
    private readonly INotifier[] _notifiers;
    public NotificationCoordinator(EmailNotifier emailNotifier, WhatsappNotifier whatsappNotifier){
        _notifiers = new INotifier[]
        {
            emailNotifier,
            whatsappNotifier
        };
    }

    public async Task HandleNotifications(Notification[] notifications){
        INotifier notifier = null;
        foreach(Notification notification in notifications){
            notifier = _notifiers.Where(n => n.Name == notification.Type).FirstOrDefault();
            if(notifier != null)
                await notifier.SendNotification(notification);

        }
    }
}
```

Based on the type attribute of the notification, it picks the correct notifier class in order to handle the notification business. This works just fine, but I got some feedback from a colleague that this could be done in a better way, but I am unsure as of how. Is there a design pattern which could be fitted for this scenario?

Comment: Ask your colleague, he made the remark.

Comment: I second sommmen. That was a pretty useless comment on your colleague's part. There are a bunch of ways to do this differently. Use a `Dictionary<string, INotifier>`, Use Visitor Pattern, ... some may perform better, some may be more readable than others, some may be more maintainable ... depends on his definition of "better".

Comment: Fair point. The guy is rather busy, should still have just asked for more input.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you're using "strategy" pattern. Anyway, it's not complete properly implemented because your class `NotificationCoordinator` breaks single responsibility principle. In such a case, you should delegate decision process of "which INotifier should be used" to the separated class eg:

```
public class NotificationStrategy : INotificationStrategy
{
    private readonly IEmailNotifier _emailNotifier;
    private readonly IWhatsappNotifier _whatsappNotifier;

    public NotificationStrategy(IEmailNotifier emailNotifier, IWhatsappNotifier whatsappNotifier)
    {
        _emailNotifier = emailNotifier;
        _whatsappNotifier = whatsappNotifier;
    }

    public INotifier GetNotifier(Notification notification)
    {
        // Notifies selection logic HERE
    }
}
```

now you have to change `NotificationCoordinator` CTOR and use `NotificationStrategy` as a dependency. Next in `HandleNotifications` you use `GetNotifier` to get the correct Notifier. Of course, you should avoid using concrete classes of eg. `Notification` - you should replace it with some abstraction.

Comment: I don't see a reason to have both `NotificationCoordinator` and `NotificationStrategy` here. `NotificationCoordinator` literally does one thing, implement the strategy, why do you want to add another abstraction?

Comment: I share that question with @Beyers. The added abstraction seems unnecessary.
I also don't quite follow your thought behind avoiding the concrete class Notification? The Notification class is solely a stand alone model containing the data such as the message to be sent.

Comment: @RobinvanderPlas ... and yet it "knows" by what means it shall be sent. But we can digress into endless architectural discussions now. Fact is: what is the goal of optimization? Is SO the correct place for this question in the first place? It _works_ right? Maybe better suited on CodeReview? ...

Comment: Bayers, Robin if you don't know why you should separate the concerns then you have to read about SOLID principles. In case od Notification and "abstraction" you may be right, but only if it's a POCO object - you didn't show it's implementation so it's hard to say. In my answer i also assumed that you know what's DI and you use it. 
As you guys said, your implementation works and it will work until you'll have to change somethings, then problem will arrive ;)

Comment: @Posio I'm not arguing against SOLID. My question is why do you think `NotificationCoordinator` breaks single responsibility principle? It literally only does one thing and that is implement the strategy.

Comment: Choosing correct implementation (strategy) and handling notification isn't the same thing. In 'HandleNotification' both things happen.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say this solution is better, but at least is different and it is based on dependency injection:

```
public class Notification
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Recipients { get; set; }
}

public interface INotifier
{
    Task SendAsync(Notification notification);
}

public class WhatsAppNotifier : INotifier
{
    public Task SendAsync(Notification notification)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class EmailNotifier : INotifier
{
    public Task SendAsync(Notification notification)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class NotifierFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
    public NotifierFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    public INotifier Get(string name)
    {
        return serviceProvider.GetNotifier(name);
    }
}

public class GeneralNotifier : INotifier
{

    private readonly NotifierFactory notifierFactory;
    public GeneralNotifier(NotifierFactory notifierFactory)
    {
        this.notifierFactory = notifierFactory;
    }

    public Task SendAsync(Notification notification)
    {
        var notifier = notifierFactory.Get(notification.Type);
        return notifier.SendAsync(notification);
    }
}

public class BulkNotifier
{
    private readonly INotifier notifier;

    public BulkNotifier(INotifier notifier)
    {
        this.notifier = notifier;
    }

    public async Task SendNotificationsAsync(IEnumerable<Notification> notifications)
    {
        foreach (var notification in notifications)
        {
            await notifier.SendAsync(notification);
        }
    }
}

public static class DependencyInjection
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Type> notifierByName = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    private static IServiceCollection AddScopedNotifier<T>(this IServiceCollection services, string name) where T: class, INotifier 
    {
        notifierByName[name] = typeof(T);
        return services.AddScoped<T>();
    }

    public static INotifier GetNotifier(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider, string name)
    {
        if (!notifierByName.TryGetValue(name, out Type notifierType))
        {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException($"{name} notifier is not registered with the depencency injection container. Please call IServiceCollection.AddNotifier");

        }
        return (INotifier)serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(notifierType);
    }

    public static IServiceCollection AddNotifiers(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return services
            .AddScopedNotifier<WhatsAppNotifier>("whatsapp")
            .AddScopedNotifier<EmailNotifier>("email")
            .AddScoped(serviceProvider => new NotifierFactory(serviceProvider))
            .AddScoped<INotifier, GeneralNotifier>()
            .AddScoped<BulkNotifier>();
    }

}
```

In your ConfigureServices method just add the following line:

```
services.AddNotifiers();
```

Then your services and controllers can take a dependency on `BulkNotifier` or `INotifier`